# How to Join two table using where and sum statement

Tags: sql

Dear All I have below two table

Table1

```
RecdId  RecdNo  
1   A/1 
2   A/2 
3   A/3
```

Table2

```
RecdId  RecdAmt1    RecdAmt2    RecdAmt3
1   100 10  5
1   150 20  10
1   200 30  15
2   500 5   50
2   400 10  60
3   100     5
```

I want solution that how to join above two table with sum of `Table1.RecdId = Tabble2.RecdId`

Below result I require

```
RecdId  RecdNo  TotRecdAmt1 TotRecdAmt2 TotRecdAmt3
1   A/1 450 60  30
2   A/2 900 15  110
3   A/3 100     5
```

Thanking You,

Comment: What's the deal with `Table1.RecdNo` - is it supposed to be numeric or string?

Comment: Dear Phil, Table1.Recdid is Numeric but Table1.RecdNo is String only

Answer (score 1):

You can `inner join` two tables and use a `group by` clause to calculate `sum` for each combination of `RecdId` and `RecdNo`:

```
select t1.RecdId
     , t1.RecdNo
     , sum(t2.RecdAmt1) as TotRecdAmt1
     , sum(t2.RecdAmt2) as TotRecdAmt2
     , sum(t2.RecdAmt3) as TotRecdAmt3
from tbl1 t1 
join tbl2 t2 on t1.RecdId = t2.RecdId
group by t1.RecdId
       , t1.RecdNo
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b9be/1)

Comment: @Phil Walton: Thanks for putting a fiddle together.

Comment: I was literally about to post my answer when I saw yours pop up, and I didn't want the work to go to waste. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.RECDID, T1.RECDNO, TotRecdAmt1, TotRecdAmt2, TotRecdAmt3 
FROM TABLE1 T1, (SELECT RECdID, SUM(RecdAmt1) TotRecdAmt1, SUM(RecdAmt2) TotRecdAmt2, 
                   SUM(RecdAmt3) TotRecdAmt3 FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY RECdID) T2 
WHERE T1.RECdID = T2.RECDID;
```

Comment: Thanks venki, i got my result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.RecdId,RecdNo,SUM(RecdAmt1) AS TotRecdAmt1,
SUM(RecdAmt2) AS TotRecdAmt2,
SUM(RecdAmt3) AS TotRecdAmt3
FROM Table1,Table2
WHERE Table1.RecdId=Table2.RecdId
GROUP BY Table1.RecdId,RecdNo
```